# Unwanted gap between top margin and text caused by tikzpicture overlay

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, atbegshi

I have the following code based on atbegshi, tikz and a boolean switch to insert pages with a sidebar:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.0cm,noheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi,ifthen,tikz,lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newboolean{DrawSidebar}
\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{false}
\AtBeginShipout{\ifthenelse{\boolean{DrawSidebar}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
  \fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle ++(5.0cm,-\paperheight);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}{}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{true}
\newgeometry{left=6.0cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,noheadfoot}

\lipsum[1-15]

\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{false}
\restoregeometry

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

This works quite well, but there is an unwanted gap between the top margin and the text on all pages with sidebar:

[image]

I can remove the gap by commenting out the `tikzpicture` code in `\AtBeginShipout`. So I assume that it is related to the `tikzpicture` which is quite surprising to me since it is an overlay.

What can I do to remove this gap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a version that produces the desired result:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.0cm,noheadfoot,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{atbegshi,ifthen,tikz,lipsum}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newboolean{DrawSidebar}
\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{false}
\AtBeginShipout{%
    \setbox\AtBeginShipoutBox=\hbox{\ifthenelse{\boolean{DrawSidebar}}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
        \fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle ++(5.0cm,-\paperheight);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }{}%
    \box\AtBeginShipoutBox
    }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\newgeometry{left=6.0cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.0cm,bottom=1.0cm,noheadfoot}
\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{true}

\lipsum[1-15]

\restoregeometry
\setboolean{DrawSidebar}{false}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first modification is the resetting of the the current shipout box in `\AtBeginShipout`. We just put the current box into another and prepend the TikZ picture (if necessary).

Another modification is required: Set the `DrawSidebar` switch *after* you've changed the page geometry. Otherwise the overlay is already drawn when the shipout of the current page occurs, putting it always one page to early.

I'm not entirely sure what goes on in your version. Probably the box is set and the TikZ picture is moved on to the next page where it causes an extra, empty line in the output. At least that's the only sensible explanation I can think of why the overlays occur at the correct pages in your version.